# How to extract username from 3rd party social logins via Useraccounts package?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

Im using Useraccounts package for Meteor.

I have configured it, the username/email + password login is working with username showing up upon login (user needs to input username on registration).

However when I click social login buttons to login, I am logged in but there is no username registered. So whatever I do that logs username will show nothing, i.e no username.

I followed the following link for configuration: 
*[**useraccounts link to 3rd party login**](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#3rd-party-login-services-configuration)*

I have the below in **lib/config.js**

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
      { "service": "facebook" },
      {
        $set: {
          "appId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      },
      { upsert: true }
    );
```

The below to modify the email/password login

```
var pwd = 
AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');
AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');
AccountsTemplates.addFields([
  {
    _id: "username",
    type: "text",
    required: true,
    displayName: "username",
    minLength: 5,
    errStr: 'error.minChar'
  },
```

I might have missed it big but I dont see any discussion on extracting usernames from 3rd party login. Does anyone know how to further configure? For example, if Facebook or Twitter username is ABC, I want ABC to be reflected as username in the app upon 3rd party social login.

**Update**

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  if(user.services){

    if(user.services.google) {
      user.username = user.services.google.username;
    } 
    else if(user.services.twitter) {
      user.username = user.services.twitter.username;
    } 
    else if(user.services.facebook) {
      user.username = user.services.facebook.username;
    }
    else if(user.services.github) {
      user.username = user.services.github.username;
    }
  }
  if(options.profile){
    user.profile = options.profile;
  }
  return user;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register a server-side hook upon user creation, and force the username to be whatever you want, including the username from 3rd party services.

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  if(user.services){
    if(user.services.google){
      user.username = user.services.google.name;
    }
    else if(user.services.twitter){
      [..]
    }
    [...]
  }
  //
  if(options.profile){
    user.profile = options.profile;
  }
  return user;
});
```

Note however that this won't enforce username uniqueness as 2 persons on facebook can share the same name obviously, so you'll have to figure it out yourself if it's a concern in your app.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do I need to put the above together with the rest at lib/config.js file? or to put in server/config.js since you mentioned its a server hook? As for uniqueness of username, thats preferred but yeah have to find out how to implement that.

Comment: Since it's a server-only API, it's best put under the `server` directory.

Comment: got it, im asking as useraccounts is not the original package for ui-accounts and im not sure if there might be conflicts. Would you happen to know if accounts-entry might be easier to handle/ configure versus Useraccounts?

Comment: These packages act as wrappers around Meteor core Accounts API, but you can still hook up with the standard API. Personally I use `useraccounts` for some of my projects but it's an opiniated topic.

Comment: The popular Telescope open-source project is using `useraccounts`, you can check the repo here : https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope The user management logic is handled in a dedicated `telescope-users` package.

Comment: Hi saimeunt, I have added the lines and attached above. username still does not show? What else would I need to resolved? Do I need to add a template helper?

Comment: Each service username is actually not named `username`, see in my code example how I fetch a `name` property from `user.services.google` ? You have to search yourself how each service names its field containing the username you want to store under your Meteor user object.